# azure app config not able to refresh in my spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, app-config, azure-app-configuration

I have tried both manual refresh and auto refresh described on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/enable-dynamic-configuration-java-spring-app#use-automated-refresh
However, it still cannot get the updated values in the app config when I refresh the page.
I even set the refresh interval to 10s.
This is the bootstrap.properties file.

```
spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].connection-string=${APP_CONFIGURATION_CONNECTION_STRING}
spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].monitoring.enabled=true
spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].monitoring.triggers[0].key=sentinel
spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].monitoring.refresh-interval= 10s
```

I have both of the dependency in my pom.xml file.

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
      <artifactId>azure-spring-cloud-appconfiguration-config</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
      <artifactId>azure-spring-cloud-appconfiguration-config-web</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have followed every steps on the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/enable-dynamic-configuration-java-spring-app#use-automated-refresh
Expected value can refresh, but actually it remain the old value after I update the values and the sentinel.

Comment: are you seeing the log of them getting refreshed https://microsoft.github.io/spring-cloud-azure/docs/azure-app-configuration/2.9.0/reference/html/index.html#configuration-refresh. Also, are your configurations in the refresh scope?